# How to make fixed width for all bars in apexcharts bar column width

Tags: javascript, html, css, apexcharts

Since we are using dynamic data, the data length should also be dynamic. For example, if data length is 24 column width should be 35px. if data is 2 length that time also column width should be 35px.

apexchart using columnWidth in percentage so i am not able to specify exact width for all bars in all condition if there is 1 Bar, 5 Bar, 30 Bars. it is working as responsive behaviour but i want to make it fixed width for all Bars

1. [image]
2. [image]

I want columnWidth to fixed with 1st image size when there is 1 data also. see in 2nd graph columnWidth is showing bigger than previous. so i want fixed for all bars in all case.

Using:
import ApexCharts from "react-apexcharts";
"react-apexcharts": "^1.3.6",

Answer (score 2):

In ApexCharts, there is no option to give `columnWidth` in pixels. You can maybe try to set percentage width based on the number of categories present. It won't be 100% accurate but might just solve the purpose.

With the chart width (w), a series of data (n), and the desired column width in px (x), I can get the width in percentage with this function:

```
const getPercentWidth = (w, n, x) => {
  const percentWidth = Math.round((x / (w / n)) * 100)
  return `${percentWidth}%`
}
```

You can check this [issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/1533) on their github repo for more options in future.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to the problem: [Apexcharts max width on item bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395784/apexcharts-max-width-on-item-bars)

The solution provided in the linked resource should help you address the issue you were facing, but i've added one more thing to make it better.

To obtain a mathematical function where the value increases more slowly as the dataset length increases, you can use a logarithmic function at columnWidth property:

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    columnWidth:
      optimalColumnWidthPercent *
        Math.log(xAxisPointsArray.length + 1) *
        30 +
      "%",
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
}
```

To better suit your needs, you can modify the value "30" part in the function.